# How to implement setNeedsReload / setNeedsRefresh

Tags: ios, uiview, refresh

I've been wondering about extending UIView with a sort of `setNeedsRefresh` method of my own - a method that behaves like `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` but with the purpose of refreshing/reloading visible data, hiding views, etc.  My goals would be to:

1. Be able to detach methods (particularly setters) from having to instantly refresh views.
2. Be able to flag a view for refresh rather than refreshing it manually (in order to optimize code execution and have a cleaner code architecture).

I was hoping to be able to extend UIView in such a way that you can call `setNeedsRefresh` on any view, and have it execute `refreshView` or some similar method before redrawing happens.

PS: is the best way to handle this through `setNeedsLayout` + a refresh flag?

**Update #1:** The following is an example of what I want to be able to do:

```
-(void)setAvailableForPurchase:(BOOL)availableForPurchase
{
    if (_availableForPurchase != availableForPurchase)
    {
        _availableForPurchase = availableForPurchase;
        [self setNeedsRefresh];
    }
}
```

And then:

```
-(void)refreshView
{
    if (self.isAvailableForPurchase)
    {
        self.someView.image = someImage;
        self.someButton.enabled = yes;
        // more code, changes several objects
    }
    else
    {
        // some other code...
    }
}
```

This example is a very simple one on purpose to better express my requirement - the reasons why I need/want to do this are listed in my initial question.

Comment: What is wrong with setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: What I want to do is not flag the view for redraw, but rather flag the view for data-refreshing/reloading.  I'll update my post with some more info.

Comment: You can call setNeedsLayout for your UIView and implement the layoutSubviews method in the UIView for reload or refresh the data. Attends your requirements?

Comment: Part of the reason why I was trying to avoid that approach is that `layoutSubviews` seems to have a different purpose altogether.  For instance a frame change would trigger it even if the data doesn't need to be reloaded.  Adding a flag to check in `layoutSubviews` if data really needs to be reloaded would fix this (I mentioned this in my P.S.), but I was looking for cleaner ways to do the same - if there's any.